# Search tkinter text widget contents using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, tkinter, tcl

In `tkinter text widget`, how to search for a whole word. I tried to use the following syntax, but it didn't match anything although the word already exists:

```
index = self.text.search(r'\b%s\b' % myWord, INSERT, backwards=True, regexp=True)
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression specified is interpreted by `tcl`, not by `python`.

Tcl use different syntax for word boundary: `\y` instead of `\b`. (See [Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), especially *Tcl Word Boundaries* part.)

The line should be replaced with:

```
index = self.text.search(r'\y%s\y' % myWord, INSERT, backwards=True, regexp=True)
```